# How to specify global MVC layout without specifying layout path in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, inheritance, razor

I'm trying to get away from having to manually specify the layout path in every Razor view that I have / create.

So in a razor view, you would normally specify the view / layout properties such as:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ContentLayout.cshtml";
}
```

I have a base controller that all my controllers are inheriting, in which I would love to be able to specify the layout at this level, or alternatively in app_start etc.

For any exceptions I would just override this in the view itself.

After an extensive search, I haven't found any evidence of anyone being able to do this yet.

My current, next-best workaround is to specify this in the ViewBag, to keep it dynamic, but I still need to put a declaration in the view:

```
@{
  Layout = ViewBag.Layout;
}
```

Is it possible? Solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts

Since MVC3 there is a convention where...

> You can add a file called _ViewStart.cshtml (or _ViewStart.vbhtml for VB)
>   underneath the `\Views` folder of your project:
>
> The _ViewStart file can be used to define common view code that you
>   want to execute at the start of each View’s rendering. For example, we
>   could write code within our _ViewStart.cshtml file to programmatically
>   set the Layout property for each View to be the `_ContentLayout.cshtml` file
>   by default:
>
> ```
> @{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ContentLayout.cshtml";}
> ```
>
> Because this code executes at the start of each View, we no longer
>   need to explicitly set the Layout in any of our individual view files
>   (except if we wanted to override the default value above).

Comment: Believe this answers my question and yes seems I already have that file, thanks! But can this be applied on a controller basis, ie. have a default template for each controller ?

Comment: You can do this in the `_ViewStart` as well. you can easily do a condition statement and check the controller. depending on controller you set the `Layout` to suit.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Nkosi, if you want to adapt the layout to a per controller basis without specifying the layout path in the view, you could do a condition block in the _ViewStart file.

But what I've found also works and is a tiny bit easier...

- Place a `_ViewStart` file in each view folder (which relates to a controller), which you want to have a different layout.
- The more specific `_ViewStart` in the View Area folder overrides the global `_ViewStart` file.

[image: Specifying different layouts in each folder]

Comment: That is much easier than my conditional suggestion. I completely missed the nested view start.